# udev rule making link to the wrong object

Tags: udev

I use a udev rule to detect a USB drive (spinning rust) that I use for off-line archiving.
For some years this has worked fine.
Recently the link that the rule creates points to a usb bus number and not /dev/sdxxx.
System is OpenSUSE 15.4. Is a known udev or systemd update known to cause this?

Tried renaming the rule in case of reserved words, tried changing the priority - noeffect.

Rule:
85-backup_usb.rules

Contents:
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",ATTRS{product}=="AS2115",GROUP="users",SYMLINK="USBDRIVE"

Formerly produced a symlink /dev/USBDRIVE -> /dev/sdxxxx
Now produces /dev/USBDRIVE -> bus/usb/002/005

Which isn't helpful.

Comment: I found an older PC with OpenSUSE15.4 but not fully updated.This works fine, so something has changed in udev or systemd.

Comment: Upgraded a test PC to OpenSUSE15.5 - same problem sadly.

Comment: Just for information: Debian 10 and 12 produce the 'correct' response  /dev/USBDRIVE -> /dev/sdxxxx